# Invoking a WPF command from a WPF-embedded Winforms control

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, command, winforms-interop

I have a `WinDataGrid` class that extends from an Infragistics `UltraGrid`.  I have embedded my `WinDataGrid` within a WPF usercontrol using `WindowsFormHost`. When rows are selected, I need to invoke a predefined `DelegateCommand<IList>` with my collection of selected rows.

How would I go about this?

As background, I have a WPF app that uses both a WPF DataGrid and an Infragistics WinGrid.  The WPF grid is already mostly wired up, and I want to utilize the existing commands etc as much as possible in wiring up my Winforms grid.  I realise there may be some mapping required, but figure I should be able to map most things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `DelegateCommand` is an `ICommand` you can call the `Execute()` method to invoke the command. Don't forget to first check if the command is allowed to execute with `CanExecute()`